# Is it possible to fetch count of total number of docs that contain a qualifying aggregation condition in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I use ES v7.3 and as per my requirements I am aggregating some fields to fetch the required docs in response, further their is a requirement to fetch the count of total number of all such docs also that contain the nested field which qualifies the aggregation condition as described below but I did not find a way where I am able to do that.

Current aggregation query that I am using to fetch the documents is,

```
"aggs": {
    "users": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "users": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "co_profileId.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "size": 5000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sessions": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "co_score"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "last_4_days": {
              "filter": {
                "range": {
                  "co_score.sessionTime": {
                    "gte": "2021-01-10T00:00:31.399Z",
                    "lte": "2021-01-14T01:37:31.399Z"
                  }
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "score_count": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "co_score.value"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "page_view_count_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "sessionCount": "sessions  > last_4_days > score_count"
            },
            "script": "params.sessionCount > 100"
          }
        },
        "filtered_users": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "co_profileId",
                "co_type",
                "co_score"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Sample doc:

```
{
    "co_profileId": "14654325",
    "co_type": "identify",
    "co_updatedAt": "2021-01-11T11:37:33.499Z",
    "co_score": [
        {
            "value": 3,
            "sessionTime": "2021-01-09T01:37:31.399Z"
        },
        {
            "value": 3,
            "sessionTime": "2021-01-10T10:47:33.419Z"
        },
        {
            "value": 6,
            "sessionTime": "2021-01-11T11:37:33.499Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you indicate which aggregation exactly? The terms one or top_hits?

Comment: the response of top_hits aggregation provides me with the source fields which i require and that was my final response needed so the total number of docs that filter till top_hits is needed

Comment: In each of the buckets of the composite aggregation, you have a `doc_count` field which indicates exactly how many documents are in each bucket.

Comment: yes and in my case each bucket has doc_count value as 1 so if I can get the total number of buckets that are retained by the bucket_selector aggregation then I will eventually get the total number of qualified docs also composite aggregation was needed for paginating the response and for fetching the count I would make a separate request without composite agg as I need the total count of docs that are qualified without pagination.

Comment: So that means that `co_profileId.keyword` is unique across all your documents?

Comment: yes, it is unique

Comment: I'm confused... If each bucket only contains a single doc, then `SUM(co_score.value)` would be equal to `co_score.value` itself, and you could simply have a normal query testing the `score > 100` condition, no need to aggregate anything. Or am I missing something?

Comment: sorry but i forgot to mention that co_score is a nested field having objects that contains different values

Comment: That doesn't really make any difference. it's like having a top-level field with the SUM of all nested scores and testing the condition on that field

Comment: I did not understood what you wanted to say, let me give u an instance here suppose I have a nested field where I maintain day wise objects that contains page_viewed_count of a user for a day and now suppose if I wanted to check that in last 7 days if the users has viewed more that 10 pages then the user doc must get qualified.. and to do so I have to aggregate page_viewed_count values for last 7 days and then apply condition on the value returned by sum aggregation.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear from the context that you had a query part with a date range already

Comment: yes, I missed to mention it.

Comment: Would you mind showing one sample document?

Comment: sir I have added a sample doc.

Comment: Did you found a solution for the problem?

Comment: I'm wondering why you decided to go with nested documents? It would be much more easy, natural and future-proof if you had one document per session, instead of continuously adding nested documents to an existing top-level document. Can you share any insight regarding that?

Comment: Actually I have a parent child relationship in my index, and as you said I introduced session docs as new child and maintained session wise docs in my index but then the aggregation query was taking much more time than as expected to paginate the results and was not at all efficient, so i thought of maintaining session data in parent docs inside a nested field where each object will have data not for a single session but for a full day(it will also help in reducing the number of nested objects) as I need to query it on date range.

Comment: Still, design-wise it would be much more optimal to have one session per document, i.e. no nested data and no parent/child relationship either (you most probably don't need it)

Comment: parent child relationship is not to fulfill this usecase, their are other requirements which are answered with the help of parent child relationship, this whole session problem is just an addition to implement a new feature to an existing app.

Comment: Can you also add the query part please?

Comment: query is not always same it can change but at the end it will always return the parent docs on which this aggregation needs to be applied inside parent docs to further filter the results, basically we are providing segmentation and so query is always based on rules made by client and their is a fixed date range over which this query runs.

Comment: is there no possibility to get total qualified docs count when using aggregation with query?

Comment: Sir suppose as u said we go with the approach of having one doc per session then also we will have to aggregate the results in order to get the desired response over a time range, so in that case will we be able to get the total docs count that qualify the aggregation condition?

Comment: So, for a given time range you need to figure out the top session with score > 100 for each profile? Am I getting this right?

Comment: NO, I want to figure out such profiles who have the the sum of score value > 100 over a time range, consider each session will have its individual score

Comment: but aggregation would still be needed to sum the score values...?

Comment: The thing is that in your current aggregation I don't see any time range constraint over the nested session docs. Right now you're summing ALL sessions whatever their time component.

Comment: I have just mentioned it in the above query.

Comment: Ok, now it looks consistent with what you've been describing all along, without that time filter, it didn't really make sense

Comment: my bad, I thought to keep things simple here so I just posted it partially.

Comment: Good, I stand by what I said initially, standalone session docs will get you where you want.

Comment: could you please elaborate, as to how will we avoid aggregation?

Comment: Of course the aggregation will still be there, but much simpler and it will be able to give you the number of docs you're interested in. With nested, it's not possible to know how many nested docs satisfy the condition

Comment: let me clarify here I never wanted to know the number of nested docs that satisfy the condition, I wanted to know the number of parent docs that contain that nested field which qualified the above condition

Comment: so in the above scenario the sample doc is a qualifying doc if condition would be sum(value) > 8 for the above mentioned time range in query, so i want the count value to be returned as 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227251/discussion-between-yash-tandon-and-val).